# Using Root & Nested owned type in multi entities migration error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2, owned-types

I getting an error, when I try to using a owned type in multi entities. I think I got the error because `User` has used the same type. Using same type in multi entities isn't supports by EF core?

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location' cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists.

```
public class User : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo UserContactInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Listing : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo ListingContactInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo : IOwnedType
{
    public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }
    public Location GeoLocation { get; set; }
}

public class Location : IOwnedType
{
    public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point Coords { get; set; }
    public Address PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
}
public class Address : IOwnedType
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }
}
//User modelBuilder
userBuilder.OwnsOne(c => c.UserContactInfo, conInfo =>
{
    conInfo.ToTable("UsersContactInfo");
    conInfo.OwnsOne(ci => ci.GeoLocation, location =>
    {
        location.OwnsOne(x => x.PhysicalAddress, address =>
        {
            address.ToTable("UsersPhysicalAddresses");
        });
        location.Property(x => x.Coords).HasColumnType("geography");
        location.ToTable("UsersLocations");
    });
});
//Listing modelBuilder
listingBuilder.OwnsOne(c => c.ListingContactInfo, conInfo =>
{
    conInfo.ToTable("ListingsContactInfo");
    conInfo.OwnsOne(ci => ci.GeoLocation, location =>
    {
        location.OwnsOne(x => x.PhysicalAddress, address =>
        {
            address.ToTable("ListingsPhysicalAddresses");
        });
        location.Property(x => x.Coords).HasColumnType("geography");
        location.ToTable("ListingsLocations");
    });
});
```

file: 13980720151831_Initial_I.Designer.cs#line2808

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Hitasp.Tradegram.Authorization.Users.User", b =>
{
    b.OwnsOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.ContactInfo", "UserContactInfo", b1 =>
    {
        b1.Property<Guid>("UserId");
        b1.Property<string>("WebsiteUrl");
        b1.HasKey("UserId");
        b1.ToTable("UserContactInfo");
        b1.HasOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Authorization.Users.User")
            .WithOne("UserContactInfo")
            .HasForeignKey("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.ContactInfo", "UserId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        b1.OwnsOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location", "GeoLocation", b2 =>
             {
                b2.Property<Guid>("ContactInfoUserId");
                b2.Property<Point>("Coords")
                    .HasColumnType("geography");

                b2.HasKey("ContactInfoUserId");
                b2.ToTable("UserLocations");

                b2.HasOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.ContactInfo")
                    .WithOne("GeoLocation")
                    .HasForeignKey("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location", "ContactInfoUserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                b2.OwnsOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Address", "PhysicalAddress", b3 =>
                    {
                        b3.Property<Guid>("LocationContactInfoUserId");
                        b3.Property<string>("AddressLine1");
                        b3.Property<string>("ZipPostalCode");
                        b3.HasKey("LocationContactInfoUserId");
                        b3.ToTable("UserPhysicalAddresses");

                        b3.HasOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location")
                            .WithOne("PhysicalAddress")
                            .HasForeignKey("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Address", "LocationContactInfoUserId")
                            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                    });
            });
        });
});
```

file: 13980720151831_Initial_I.Designer.cs#line3019

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Hitasp.Tradegram.Listings.Listing", b =>
{
    b.OwnsOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.ContactInfo", "ListingContactInfo", b1 =>
    {
        b1.Property<Guid>("ListingId");
        b1.Property<string>("WebsiteUrl");
        b1.HasKey("ListingId");
        b1.ToTable("ListingContactInfo");
        b1.HasOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Listings.Listing")
            .WithOne("ListingContactInfo")
            .HasForeignKey("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.ContactInfo", "ListingId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        b1.OwnsOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location", "GeoLocation", b2 =>
             {
                b2.Property<Guid>("ContactInfoListingId");
                b2.Property<Point>("Coords")
                    .HasColumnType("geography");

                b2.HasKey("ContactInfoListingId");
                b2.ToTable("ListingLocations");

                b2.HasOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.ContactInfo")
                    .WithOne("GeoLocation")
                    .HasForeignKey("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location", "ContactInfoListingId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                b2.OwnsOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Address", "PhysicalAddress", b3 =>
                    {
                        b3.Property<Guid>("LocationContactInfoListingId");
                        b3.Property<string>("AddressLine1");
                        b3.Property<string>("ZipPostalCode");
                        b3.HasKey("LocationContactInfoListingId");
                        b3.ToTable("ListingPhysicalAddresses");

                        b3.HasOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location")
                            .WithOne("PhysicalAddress")
                            .HasForeignKey("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Address", "LocationContactInfoListingId")
                            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                    });
            });
        });
});
```

#### Further technical details

EF Core version: 2.2.6
Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Target framework: .NET Core 2.2
Operating system: Windows 10
IDE: Rider 2019.2.2

Answer (score 0):

With Andriy (from EF's team) comment [in github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18350#issuecomment-541351249) my problem was solved

> You would need to remove the b3.HasOne("Hitasp.Tradegram.Types.Location") line and the following calls. Or upgrade to 3.0.0 and use the WithOwner method instead.